# PHP Call method at end of chain

Tags: php, chaining

I have a class that is utilizing the Singleton principle, and I have methods that allow for chaining. At the end of them you have to call an output() method to render the class, but I'm wondering if there is any way to do this automatically. I've tried using a __destruct, but it processes to late. I need it to be done before the script exits.

```
class View {

private static $_instance = null,
               $_view;

public static $data;

private static function getInstance()
{
    // Instantiate the class
    if( self::$_instance === null ){
        self::$_instance = new self;
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
public static function make( $view )
{
    $instance = self::getInstance();
    $file = explode( '.', $view );
    $file = DIR . 'core/views/' . $file[0] . '/' . $file[1] . '.php';
    self::$_view = $file;
    return $instance;
}
public function with($data)
{
    self::$data = $data;
    return $this;
}
```

}

it would be utilized like so:

```
return View::make($view)->with($data);
```

Comment: Singletons in PHP make about as much sense as snowshoes do on a summer holiday: PHP is stateless, singletons are mere globals in disguise. Why not create three global functions instead, and pass what you need to them?

Comment: You should just have a look at the Laravel source code because it looks like you are trying to emulate it.

Comment: @true Lol good guess! I'm trying to utilize its structure in a WP plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there's something which is expecting the return value, and echoing it out (e.g. a controller)? If so, you could make use of the `__toString()` magic method for your View class:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->output();
}
```

Theoretical logic:

```
$view = $controller->getIndex() // Returns your View instance
echo $view; // Magically converted to a string
```

Side note, you can also use this with casting:

```
$view = (string) View::make($view)->with($data); // will be the rendered view
```

One important thing to note about `__toString()` is an exception cannot be thrown within the function (i.e. your view cannot throw one). If one is thrown, PHP will actually throw a less than helpful "__toString() cannot thrown an exception" exception.

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest this, but why not just `echo View::make($view)->with($data);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) but that would require the `$this` context.

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    // ...
    // check if the current method being called is the last one needed, then
    // render the view output
    if ('lastMethod' == $method) {
        $this->render();
    }
}
```

Here in the example, if you know the name of the last method that needs to be called *before* the view rendering happens, then you can have it called automatically.  Although, I would recommend rewriting much of your `View` class anyway.